# A word for when somebody deflects from a conversation?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to fill in this blank.

> "I'm certain of it: the square root of 225 is 25," said Peter. But when Mary pulled out her phone and used the calculator app to find that it was in fact 15, Peter recoiled. In a quick ___, he redirected, adding, "But you know, this reminds me of a funny story involving Euler..."

The word I'm looking for would mean a deflection from a conversational faux pas by redirecting the conversation. It could describe making an excuse for one's flub, but not necessarily. I've thought of some related verbs like *redirect, deflect, rebound, recover*, and so on, but I'm looking for a noun, and one that pertains particularly to talking. *Tangent* (as in, "going off on a tangent") is relevant, though that doesn't have the connotation of recovering for a mistake.

I really feel like at some point, the French must have invented a word for this, and then we stole it. Alternatively, a word for a deflection from a generally uncomfortable conversation would also work.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45205/discussion-on-question-by-kevin-long-a-word-for-when-somebody-deflects-from-a-co).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could say that

> In a quick [side step](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/side%20step), he redirected [the conversation].

Also often spelled [*sidestep*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sidestep).

> A motion, physical or metaphorical, to avoid or dodge something.

This describes a physical dodging motion to the side rather than forward, but it can also be used as a metaphorical action to avoid a topic in a conversation.

The verb form is [*sidestep*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sidestep).

Comment: +1 ... In light of the alternate, single-word spelling you mention (reconfirmed [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sidestep)), this seems to be a very good answer to the OP’s single-word request.

Comment: +1 "Dodge" can be a noun as well as a verb. "In a quick dodge, Peter shoehorned a non-sequitur into the conversation by saying, "But you know, this reminds me . . .."

Comment: You could also use manoeuvre (which means "move skilfully or carefully"). "In a quick manoeuvre, he redirected.." Manoeuvre implies a movement, but it is less specific about the nature of the movement than 'sidestep' or 'dodge'

Answer (score 26):

***Change of subject*** would fill in the blank in a natural, American-English way. I don't know of a single word that would do it without sounding contrived.

In conversation if someone tries to redirect the conversation to avoid some topic, and the other party catches on, it is often called out with "Don't change the subject"

*Change the subject* — [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/change-the-subject)

> Deliberately talk about another topic, as in *If someone asks you an embarrassing question, just change the subject*. This term uses *subject* in the sense of “a topic of conversation,” a usage dating from the late 1500s.

Comment: *American and British way of doing it.

Comment: red herring https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring

Answer (score 22):

You might call this an [**evasion**](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20evasion):

> the action of evading something.
>
> "their adroit evasion of almost all questions"
>
> *synonyms:*   avoidance, elusion, circumvention, dodging, sidestepping
>
> "the evasion of immigration control"
>
> an indirect answer; a prevaricating excuse.
>
> plural noun: evasions
>
> "the protestations and evasions of a witness"
>
> *synonyms:*   prevarication, evasiveness, beating around the bush, hedging, pussyfooting, hemming and hawing, equivocation, vagueness,
>   temporization; *rare* tergiversation
>
> "she grew tired of all the evasion"

Similarly, you could say the person is being [**evasive**](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3A%20evasive):

> tending to avoid commitment or self-revelation, especially by
>   responding only indirectly.
>
> "she was evasive about her phone number"
>
> *synonyms:*   equivocal, prevaricating, elusive, ambiguous, noncommittal, vague, inexplicit, unclear; roundabout, indirect;
>   *informal* cagey, shifty, slippery
>
> "the judge was infuriated by the defendant's evasive answers"
>
> directed toward avoidance or escape.
>
> "they decided to take evasive action"
>
> *synonyms:*   equivocal, prevaricating, elusive, ambiguous, noncommittal, vague, inexplicit, unclear; roundabout, indirect;
>   *informal* cagey, shifty, slippery
>
> "the judge was infuriated by the defendant's evasive answers"

Comment: Please explain why you feel this is a suitable term for this situation.

Comment: @tchrist Um, what? I feel this is a suitable term for this situation because the word exactly fits the sentence, and it exactly matches what the OP is describing, and I've heard it used in similar contexts in the past. Can you please explain why you feel this is **not** a suitable term for this situation?

Answer (score 17):

*Diversion*. From [*The Oxford Dictionary of Difficult Words*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Vm_mNJiflwgC&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=%22instance+of+turning+something+aside+from+its+course%22&source=bl&ots=d1XVkNf8LT&sig=CJqYvH9jCAEMeDW-0i97brySlRo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwio1eDB9ILPAhUBLJQKHSLyDaUQ6AEIMDAD#v=onepage&q=%22instance%20of%20turning%20something%20aside%20from%20its%20course%22&f=false):

> **di·ver·sion**
>   **1** an instance of turning something aside from its course: *a diversion of resources from defense to civil research*

It implies an intention to avoid an expected outcome.

Comment: I identified and linked to the source of the quoted definition in your answer. Please include citations of this type in future answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

*In a quick **parry**, he redirected, adding, "But you know, this reminds me of a funny story involving Euler. . . .*

> **parry**:  an act or instance of skillfully avoiding something
>
> [...] *Parry (which is used in fencing, among other applications) probably comes from "parez," a form of the French verb parer, meaning "to guard or ward off."*
>   — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parry)

Note: I know *to parry* is normally in **self**-defence, but perhaps the noun would work.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the word *digress*:

> leave the main subject temporarily in speech or writing.

In your example,

> "I'm certain of it: the square root of 225 is 25," said Peter. But when Mary pulled out her phone and used the calculator app to find that it was in fact 15, Peter recoiled. In a quick **digress**, he added, "But you know, this reminds me of a funny story involving Euler..."

Comment: I was hoping for a word that is specifically used for after one has made a mistake, or just for some generally awkward situation, but digress may be the best word that exists. Also, In your quote, I think you want to use "digression" instead of "digress".

Comment: I believe digress fits the context. Also, I wanted to use **digress**, it is perfectly valid

Answer (score 5):

> He quickly **covered for** his error with a redirected anecdote, "Did I tell you about. . . ."

In this example *covered for* is synonymous with "hide" or "conceal" but in a duplicitous way: For example

> The girl provided an alibi for her boyfriend to **cover for** his absence during class.

Comment: I'm looking for a word particularly pertaining to conversation, but "cover" does certainly work in that context.

Answer (score 5):

### Segue

It literally means follows, in Italian, but *segue* is the word you're looking for.

> In a quick segue Peter brought up a childhood story of his.

I want to disagree with the [real definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/segue) that attributes it to stage acting.  Though, comedians often segue their topics; it's an art.  But if I were talking with a friend about oranges and suddenly he starts talking about his love for cheese, I'd say to him, "What an odd segue, my friend."

---

### Divert

You can also *[divert](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/divert)*
but to use it like a noun like *segue*, you'd have to say

> In a quick diversion. . . .

Comment: I do think I may have heard *segue* more in relation to performance than everyday conversation (though not necessarily only stage acting)

Answer (score 4):

The word ***pivot*** can mean to change direction.

> : to turn on or around a central point
> <sub>[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pivot)</sub>

This notion is applied when someone answers a question by turning the question into about some other issue. For example, in a recent news article:

> "So, he believes President Obama was born here," Conway said of Trump, quickly pivoting to an argument about Obama's performance in office.
>
> That's a smart pivot by Conway! There are many more people open to an argument about the allegedly poor job Obama has done as president than to one about how Obama was actually not born in the United States.
> <sub>[The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-fix/wp/2016/09/09/on-birtherism-donald-trumps-campaign-manager-wants-him-to-be-somebody-trump-doesnt-want-to-be/)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

You might call this a [***switch***](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%20switch) *of conversation*.

Comment: Please explain why you feel this is an answer to the question, preferably with references.

Answer (score 2):

There's another term, which like *parry* was borrowed from fencing: [*riposte*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/riposte). From www.dictionary.com:

> a quick, sharp return in speech or action; counterstroke:
>
> Fencing. a quick thrust given after parrying a lunge.

It carries the notion that one is countering from a perceived attack with another attack (as the fictional Peter may be doing).

Other possibilities are:

- *rejoinder*, "a reply, especially a sharp or witty one"
- *comeback*, "a quick reply to a critical remark"

Comment: Thank you, @trentcl, for proposing the edit (and tchrist for implementing it). I know what I wanted to type, but my fingers had another idea.

Answer (score 2):

The verb [stonewall](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stonewall) / stonewalling can work for this (plus more) and is not uncommon. From The Free Dictionary:

> v.intr., Informal
>
> - To engage in delaying tactics; stall.
> - To refuse to answer or cooperate.
>
> v.tr., Informal
>
> - To refuse to answer or cooperate with; resist or rebuff:
>
> v.
>
> - engage in delaying tactics or refuse to cooperate; "The President stonewalled when he realized the plot was being uncovered by a journalist"

It can mean many different things but generally refers to any debate tactic that defensively attempts to avoid answering a question, which includes blatantly changing the subject.

Answer (score 1):

"I'm certain of it: the square root of 225 is 25," said Peter. But when Mary pulled out her phone and used the calculator app to find that it was in fact 15, Peter recoiled. "But you know, this reminds me of a funny story involving Euler..." he hastily diverted.

Comment: Or *diversion* as in ”In a quick diversion, he redirected. . . .”

Answer (score 1):

I think I have the "French Connection" for you.  The OP's reference to the French having invented "a word for this" which "we" have now stolen — perish the thought — has me wondering about the possibility of perfidious Albion filching *volte-face*, as in

> In a quick *volte-face*, he redirected, adding. . . /

*Volte-face:* A complete change of attitude or opinion; a reversal in policy. ([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/volte%E2%80%93face))

Likewise, what about:

> In a quick verbal pirouette, he redirected, adding. . . .

- *verbal*: Relating to or in the form of words. ([ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/verbal))
- *pirouette*: A full turn of the body on the point of the toe in ballet. ([TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pirouette))

Comment: @Kevin Long  Are my suggestions above the "mots justes"?

Comment: The English phrase **about face** appears to be the equivalent of volte-face.  It's not clear that it implies the preemptive defense that the OP asks for, however.

Answer (score 1):

How about **turnabout**?

From Dictionary.com:

> [**turnabout**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/turnabout?s=t): the
>   act of turning in a different or opposite direction

The OP's example:

> In a quick **turnabout**, he redirected, adding, “But you know, this
>   reminds me of a funny story involving Euler. . . .”

As per its definition, **turnabout** corresponds to the subject's initial conscious or unconscious mental ***act*** to turn the conversation in a different or opposite direction; it ***embodies*** an internal discounting or denial of the incoming information. The subject then opts to  **redirect** the conversation, from the point of view of the other party, thereby making the mental **turnabout** "real". The other party perceives the combination of **turnabout** (internal to the subject) and **redirection** as **deflection**, experiencing only the **redirection**.

In my view, the following sentence doesn't make sufficiently clear the relationship between **deflection** and **redirection**:

> In a quick **deflection**, he redirected, adding, "But you know, this
>   reminds me of a funny story involving Euler..."

It seems to me that it would make more sense and sound better for a third-person narrator to say "In a quick **turnaround**, he redirected ..." rather than "In a quick **deflection**, he redirected ..."

Comment: Please explain why you feel this answers the question.

Comment: @tchrist I was doing that last night but kept falling asleep at my computer I didn't have confidence in my explanation, so I deleted it. I'll give it another try.

Comment: Plus one for : [deflect](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deflects) - draw someone's attention away from something; "He deflected his competitors"

Answer (score -1):

How about "to obfuscate" - such as when a politician, in a conversation,  deliberately tries to lead the listener/reader down a different path by using words that are intended to deceive, confuse, distract, or imply something altogether different. I liken it to a semantic sleight of hand.