# When a person says ONE thing to deflect attention from something ELSE

Tags: expressions

What is the term when a person says ONE thing to deflect attention from something ELSE being said or done  by the same person.

Like someone does something wrong, but talks in circles or creates another story to redirect attention from what he did or said in the first place, so the original ill is noticed less.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I strongly encourage you to read the guidance on [making single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info), and to familiarize yourself with the site [tour] and [help].

Comment: There is an "official" term in "rhetoric" (debating) for this, but I'm not up on the terms and don't have a reference at hand.

Comment: Alternative facts?

Comment: Not a duplicate but similar to http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/347646/a-word-for-when-somebody-deflects-from-a-conversation

Comment: Close one : [trump up](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/trump%20up)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269467/idiom-meaning-diverting-somebodys-attention-from-a-topic-which-you-dont-want-t

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Idiom meaning diverting somebody's attention from a topic which you don't want to talk on](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269467/idiom-meaning-diverting-somebodys-attention-from-a-topic-which-you-dont-want-t)

Comment: I appreciate everyone's input!!!

Answer (score 23):

How about **misdirection**, **deflection**, or **obfuscation**?

OD:

> [**misdirection**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/misdirection): *[mass noun]* the action or process of
> directing someone to the wrong place or in the wrong direction: *‘the
> deliberate **misdirection** that had put me off the track’*
>
> [**deflection**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deflection):
> *[mass noun]* the action or process of deflecting or being deflected
>
> [**deflect**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/deflect):
> cause (someone) to deviate from an intended purpose
>
> [**obfuscation**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/obfuscation): *[mass noun]* the action of making something obscure, unclear, or
> unintelligible: *‘when confronted with sharp questions they resort to
> **obfuscation’***

We've seen a lot of **misdirection**, **deflection**, and **obfuscation** in our political discourse of late.

Comment: Obfuscation is spot on, Richard. Though I can't think what you mean when you mention contemporary political discussion ;-)

Comment: @BoldBen Hey, Ben. Agreed. :-) I always try to hope for the best.

Comment: Obfuscation is hiding something by making it unclear and confusing in and of itself. Misdirection is closer to what the OP edited their question to say, focusing attention on one thing to distract from another thing happening at the same time. It's a staple of magicians.

Comment: Richard, my query was actually politically centered and obfuscation ( as well as another's answer of gaslighting) are spot on!!

Comment: @Suzycurious Thanks. I inferred that and answered accordingly. Good question.

Comment: @Suzycurious To get your question off of ON HOLD, you might want to add an example sentence.

Answer (score 11):

You could call it:

Creating a [**Distraction**](https://www.google.com/search?q=distraction&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Tm6GWKS0D-TX8gfPkbu4CA)

> a thing that prevents someone from giving full attention to something else.

And from Merriam Webster:

> : something that makes it difficult to think or pay attention
>
> : something that amuses or entertains you so that you do not think about problems, work, etc

The verb **distract**,

> "He distracted attention from the problem by talking about the weather."

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit formal and might not be in the entire audience's vocabulary, but that being said, you might consider:

***subterfuge***

(Also, it doesn't apply only to distracting speech.. your question is a bit unclear on that)

> [subterfuge](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subterfuge)
>
> 1
>   :  deception by artifice or stratagem in order to conceal, escape, or evade
>
> 2
>   :  a deceptive device or stratagem

Comment: Yes, this is a good one and my query was directed more toward the actions of one who is basically trying to pull the wool over one's eyes. Saying one thing that causes a reaction in such a way as to keep the listener busy so they don't see the true nature of the deception. Does that make sense? Appreciate your input.

Answer (score 4):

You can use ***[to dodge](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/dodge)*** meaning:

> - to evade (questions, etc) by cleverness or trickery.
>
>   - *The President  dodged questions about his relationship with the actress.*

The Free Dictionary

Answer (score 4):

From a native speaker:

Use **diversion** if you mean deliberately creating one activity to divert attention from another:  "The pickpockets had a partner screaming nearby to create a **diversion** while they were stealing wallets undetected."

Use **counterfeit question** if you mean a false request for information when you are really making a statement: "If I gave you ten dollars for a cookie, why is my change only one dollar?" The question sets up a challenge more than it seeks clarification. The word 'counterfeit' is, of course, strong language.

Answer (score 4):

The thing the person says could be called a [red herring](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/red+herring), being something irrelevant which distracts from the main issue, whereas the person saying the thing is practicing [misdirection](http://thefreedictionary.com/misdirection) or creating a [distraction](http://thefreedictionary.com/distraction).

Answer (score 3):

How about **gaslighting** ?

> Gaslighting is a form of manipulation through persistent denial, misdirection, contradiction, and lying in an attempt to destabilize and delegitimize a target. Its intent is to sow seeds of doubt in the targets, hoping to make them question their own memory, perception, and sanity

Source : [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaslighting)

Comment: I saw the play "Gaslight" from which the term originated when I was a teen. Nice period piece.

Comment: I think this fits the bill!! Appreciate your input and I saw Gaslight as well, Paul Chernoch, amazing!

Answer (score 2):

A more colourful phrase is *to throw a dead cat on the table*. [Example (political)](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2016/jan/20/lynton-crosby-and-dead-cat-won-election-conservatives-labour-intellectually-lazy).  This is current in the UK, but appears to derive from Australian use.  Even when applied to Trump, most of the uses I've found are UK-based though CNN and HuffPo have both used it in this context.

Comment: I appreciate this and my query WAS  actually politically motivated!

Answer (score 2):

[**Ignoratio elenchi**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignoratio_elenchi)

> *Ignoratio elenchi*, also known as **irrelevant conclusion**, is the
>   informal fallacy of presenting an argument that may or may not be
>   logically valid, but fails nonetheless to address the issue in
>   question. More colloquially, it is also known as missing the point.
>
> *Ignoratio elenchi* falls into the broad class of relevance
>   fallacies. It is one of the fallacies identified by Aristotle in
>   his *Organon*. In a broader sense he asserted that all fallacies are a
>   form of *ignoratio elenchi*.

(*Red herring* and *straw man* are also pretty good fits to the scenario.)

Comment: +1. Why is this answer buried so deep?!

Comment: Speaking of rhetoric devices, `circumlocution`/`equivocation` are also worth mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you are looking for isn't a single word but the expression:

> They are changing the topic.

...or...

> They are changing the subject of the conversation.

When you are about to get into trouble, for example, it is a common strategy to make the accuser forget about that situation by bringing something else to the foreground.