# What is a phrase for “abruptly changing the topic or action?”

Tags: phrase-requests, idioms, idiom-requests

There is only one example I can think of, but I am looking for an alternative.

Scene is a character deciding that a discussion isn’t going towards the conclusion he is looking for, so he suddenly decides to “switch gears.”

“Change tactics” could also apply but it is not what I’m looking for.

Comment: What don't you like about "switch gears" and "change tactics"? What qualities are you looking for in the phrase?

Comment: If you'll accept a noun: [A word for when somebody deflects from a conversation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/347646/191178)

Comment: Are you looking to add this to the script as a dialogue explanation? Like this: "He will not attend that party!". (growling). Please explain your question better.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- "*[Change tack](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/change-tack)*": to try a different method to deal with the same problem
- "*[Try a different tack](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-change-tack)*": see above
- "*[Switch up](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/switch-up)*": to change, usually in a way that brings an improvement

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be looking for a Path metaphor. "Changing the subject" is usually interpreted as changing the direction of a conversation. So any term that indicates motion along a designated Path will be interpreted that way.

You see it in *taking a tack*, which means altering the direction of a ship by maneuvering the sails, *switching/shifting gears,* which means altering the speed of a machine, often preparatory to altering direction, and in *deflecting,* which usually refers to the conversation as moving along a channel or road.

Get the metaphor set up in your mind and then use phrases that it suggests.
Maybe reading [Lakoff and Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphors_We_Live_By) would be a good idea, too.

Answer (score 0):

**Pivot** works well in this context. From [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pivot)

> 4: **a usually marked change**
>
> especially : **an adjustment or modification made (as to a product, service, or strategy) in order to adapt or improve**